# [gazebo 11] How to set a default variable/parameter in xacro

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a main xacro file where I am calling another xacro as such:

```
 <xacro:include filename="$(find uuv_gazebo_ros_plugins)/urdf/thruster_snippets.xacro"/>
```

I have modified the included xacro "thruster_snippets.xacro" so that I can change the size of the thrusters if needed. (sometimes the .dae file is large and therefore needs to be scaled down). The parameter that I added was **scale** to the "**generic_thruster_macro**" and the "**thruster_module_first_order_basic_fcn_macro**".

However, I want to set a default value for scale so that I don't have to include that parameter every time I add a new robot.

Does anyone know how to do this?

This code looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- ROTOR DYNAMICS MACROS -->

  <!-- First order dynamics -->

  <xacro:macro name="rotor_dyn_first_order_macro" params="time_constant">
    <dynamics>
      <type>FirstOrder</type>
      <timeConstant>${time_constant}</timeConstant>
    </dynamics>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!--
    MACROS FOR CONVERSION FUNCTIONS BETWEEN ROTOR'S ANG. VELOCITY AND
    THRUSTER FORCE
  -->

  <!--
    1) Basic curve
      Input: x
      Output: thrust
      Function: thrust = rotorConstant * x * abs(x)
  -->
  <xacro:macro name="thruster_cf_basic_macro"
    params="rotor_constant">
    <conversion>
      <type>Basic</type>
      <rotorConstant>${rotor_constant}</rotorConstant>
    </conversion>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!--
    2) Dead-zone nonlinearity described in [1]
      [1] Bessa, Wallace Moreira, Max Suell Dutra, and Edwin Kreuzer. "Thruster
          dynamics compensation for the positioning of underwater robotic vehicles
          through a fuzzy sliding mode based approach." ABCM Symposium Series in
          Mechatronics. Vol. 2. 2006.
      Input: x
      Output: thrust
      Function:
        thrust = rotorConstantL * (x * abs(x) - deltaL), if x * abs(x) <= deltaL
        thrust = 0, if deltaL < x * abs(x) < deltaR
        thrust = rotorConstantR * (x * abs(x) - deltaR), if x * abs(x) >= deltaL
  -->
  <xacro:macro name="thruster_cf_dead_zone_macro"
    params="rotor_constant_l
            rotor_constant_r
            delta_l
            delta_r">
    <conversion>
      <type>Bessa</type>
      <rotorConstantL>${rotor_constant_l}</rotorConstantL>
      <rotorConstantR>${rotor_constant_r}</rotorConstantR>
      <deltaL>${delta_l}</deltaL>
      <deltaR>${delta_r}</deltaR>
    </conversion>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!--
    3) Linear interpolation
      If you have access to the thruster's data sheet, for example,
      you can enter samples of the curve's input and output values
      and the thruster output will be found through linear interpolation
      of the given samples.
  -->
  <xacro:macro name="thruster_cf_linear_interp_macro"
    params="input_values
            output_values">
    <conversion>
      <type>LinearInterp</type>
      <inputValues>${input_values}</inputValues>
      <outputValues>${output_values}</outputValues>
    </conversion>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!-- THRUSTER MODULE MACROS  -->

  <xacro:macro name="generic_thruster_macro"
    params="namespace
            thruster_id
            *origin
            mesh_filename
            scale
            *dynamics
            *conversion">
    <joint name="${namespace}/thruster_${thruster_id}_joint" type="continuous">
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${namespace}/base_link"/>
      <child link="${namespace}/thruster_${thruster_id}"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="${namespace}/thruster_${thruster_id}">
      <xacro:box_inertial x="0" y="0" z="0" mass="0.001">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      </xacro:box_inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="${mesh_filename}" scale="${scale}"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <!-- todo: gazebo needs a collision volume or it will ignore the pose of
           the joint that leads to this link (and assume it to be the identity) -->
        <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.000001" radius="0.000001"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="${namespace}_${thruster_id}_thruster_model" filename="libuuv_thruster_ros_plugin.so">
        <linkName>${namespace}/thruster_${thruster_id}</linkName>
        <jointName>${namespace}/thruster_${thruster_id}_joint</jointName>
        <thrusterID>${thruster_id}</thrusterID>
        <xacro:insert_block name="dynamics"/>
        <xacro:insert_block name="conversion"/>
      </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="${namespace}/thruster_${thruster_id}">
      <selfCollide>false</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!--
    Thruster model with first order dynamic model for the rotor dynamics
    and a proportional non-linear steady-state conversion from the rotor's
    angular velocity to output thrust force
  -->

  <xacro:macro name="thruster_module_first_order_basic_fcn_macro"
      params="namespace
              thruster_id
              *origin
              mesh_filename
              scale
              dyn_time_constant
              rotor_constant">
    <xacro:generic_thruster_macro
      namespace="${namespace}"
      thruster_id="${thruster_id}"
      mesh_filename="${mesh_filename}"
      scale = "${scale}">
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <xacro:rotor_dyn_first_order_macro time_constant="${dyn_time_constant}"/>
      <xacro:thruster_cf_basic_macro rotor_constant="${rotor_constant}"/>
    </xacro:generic_thruster_macro>
  </xacro:macro>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415876/%5Bgazebo-11%5D-how-to-set-a-default-variable/parameter-in-xacro/) by [anonymous53275](https://answers.ros.org/users/53275/anonymous53275/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is documented in section 7.1 of https://wiki.ros.org/xacro

Example snippet: `params="x y:=${2*y} z:=0"`

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1